# How to use javascript type effect forward and backward one by one with infinite setInterval

Tags: javascript, effect

The type effect just forward one by one I need to use also backward the sentence one by one,
please see my snippet and also look console which I wanted to apply the effect in my snippet.

```js
    let txt = 'I am from Bangladesh';
    let countForward = 0;
    let countBackward = txt.length;
    const setUpdate =   setInterval(function(){
        if(countForward >= txt.length){
            countBackward--;
            if(countBackward <=0){
                countBackward = 0;
            } else{
                let slice = txt.slice(txt.length, countBackward);
                
            }
        } else {
            countForward++;
        }

        let slice = txt.slice(0,countForward);
        console.log(countBackward)
       

        demo.innerHTML = slice;
        let sliceback = txt.length;
        
    },100)
```

```html
 <div id="demo">
```

also need it infinite setInterval that I tried but not understand how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using two separate counters, use one counter and a boolean flag that indicates the direction.

See solution:

```js
const txt = 'I am from Bangladesh';
let countingUp = true;
let count = 0;
const setUpdate = setInterval(function() {
  if (count > txt.length) {
    countingUp = false;
    count -= 2;
  } else if (count < 0) {
    countingUp = true;
    count += 2;
  }

  demo.innerHTML = txt.slice(0, count);
  count += countingUp ? 1 : -1;
}, 100)
```

```html
<div id="demo">
```

Comment: great, could you let me know, when the count==txt.length than little bit of pause than again run I tried setTimeout but not  working

Comment: that's because it runs twice when `count = txt.length` and `count = 0`. you can solve the problem by skipping one of them. updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried ` if(count > Number(txt.length + 10))` for little bit of delay added 10 with txt.length. your concept is great